# Angular: filtering multiple items from array

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I'm creating an application where you can filter items by clicking on category buttons. Most items have multiple categories. When pressing on the category buttons, I create an array with the pressed categories.

Each item to be filtered has an array for categories it belongs to.
Example:

Item 1 - categories: animal, brown, tail

Item 2 - categories: animal, white

Item 3 - categories: human, tall

When I press on the categories buttons "animal", it shows only items 1 and 2, then when I press on brown, it shows only Item 1. When I deselect all items and press in this order - animal, tail. It doesn't show anything :/

I've looked trough some of the similar topics, but haven't found a solid way of doing this.

Is it possible at all to do it without creating custom filter?

Comment: Show us your code, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Is there a reason that you don't want a custom filter? This seems like exactly the case for one, and it would be pretty trivial to create.

Comment: check out this : http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/common-user-interface-patterns/filtering-and-sorting-a-list.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you change your mind about adding a "custom filter", here's one that should work.

```
angular.module('myApp').filter('matchesAll', function() {
    return function(items, relevant, property) {
        if(!(relevant && relevant.length)){
            return items; // No categories to compare with, return everything
        }

        property = property || 'categories'; // By default look at categories

        return items.filter(function(item) {
            var itemProps = item[property];
            return relevant.every(function(relevantCategory){
                return itemProps.indexOf(relevantCategory) !== -1;
            });
        });
    };
});
```

This would be used like any `ngRepeat` filter:

```
ng-repeat="item in items | matchesAll:selectedCategories"
```

JSFiddle demonstrating it: http://jsfiddle.net/3an5wr0b/

Comment: It seems to throw an error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined". Closer insepction shows the error here: "if(!relevant && relevant.length){"

Also to note, I'm using  AngularJS v1.2.9

Comment: Sorry, I introduced that error when I lengthened the variable `prop` to `property` to make the code clearer. I missed one spot.

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem to help, even though I fixed the typo. It's as if it cannot get the value for "relevant".

Comment: When i do, "return function(items, relevant, property) {console.log(relevant);..." it outputs undefined.

Comment: Yeah, yeah. I didn't actually test it, threw it together on my phone in a hurry. Now I have, with all cases. Should work now (add the brackets around `relevant && relevant.length`). Here's a copy that shows all cases: http://jsfiddle.net/z0033dmb/1

Comment: I got it to work, but instead of filtering out things that do not contain all of the selected categories, it shows all the items which have at least one selected category :/

Comment: Ahh, I took it as "any", not "all". Fortunately it's a simple change. Updating the answer now. Here's the working "all" solution: http://jsfiddle.net/3an5wr0b/

Comment: ok, close, but now it's looking for exact match only of the categories, while it needs to show items which have same selected categories. Example - category A and category D are selected. Then it shows item 1 (A,B,C,D), item 2 (A,B,D) but item 3(A,B,C) is not shown.

Comment: I think you'll find that if you follow the JSFiddle, the example of items (A,B,C) , (B,C), and (A) will match (A,B,C) for selection (A,C). Which is exactly as you just described.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88010/discussion-between-drobinson-and-yodalr).